# How to subtract number from HP?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my C# code for HP counting.

```
public int hpNum =3;

public void Damage(int D){

  print(hpNum);
  hpNum -= D;

  if(hpNum<=0){

    print("GameOver");
  }
}
```

And I have called this in other script like below

```
gameObject.SendMessage("Damage",1);
```

I want it to minus 1 from the hpNum everytime the function Damage is called. Like the first time, it prints 3, then 2, then 1, then when it reaches 0, it prints "GameOver". However, it only prints 3 everytime in console, which means it doesn't minus anything from the hpNum.
How do I make it to minus the number from hpNum?

Comment: Please clarify a bit more, the hierarchy of the `GameObjects`, from which you are calling `SendMessage ( ... )` and the one having the said method on some script on it. That would be helpful. If you look at the documentation for [SendMessasge](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html) this is what it has to say `"Calls the method named methodName on every MonoBehaviour in this game object."`

Comment: please refer this - https://answers.unity.com/questions/39987/how-to-send-message-to-other-gameobject.html

Comment: @nIcE cOw gameObject.SendMessage("Damage",1) is called in a script for an object, and public void Damage is in another script that is also a component of the same object.

Comment: @Hally, If both the scripts are attached to the same GameObject, then it should work flawlessly. But if the function to be called is on the child, then you have to use [BroadcastMessage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.BroadcastMessage.html) or if the function to be called is on the parent of the gameObject, then you have to call [SendMessageUpwards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessageUpwards.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to update hpNum and the function to be static. It will make it static entire all the function calls which will make it change after each call.

```
public static int hpNum = 3;

public static void Damage(int D){
    print(hpNum);
    hpNum -= D;

    if (hpNum <= 0){
        print("GameOver");
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to to minus 1 from the hpNum everytime it calls the function. Like the first time, it prints 2, then 1, then 0. I am sorry that the question is unclear. I'll edit it.

Comment: There is no reason to make this static. This is not a singleton or static class I would assume. It should be an instance and you should get a hold of a reference to the instance and call the method directly